# Prove that if $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $\gcd(a,b)/d = \gcd(a/d,b/d)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

> Prove that, given $a,b,d$ integers, if $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, then $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d}=\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$.

So far I have what was given:

$a=dk$, $b=dk'$

Now: i give the $\gcd$ the next value $\gcd(a,b)=t$ and so i know that

- $t$ divides $a$ then $a=t*t'$
- $t$ divides $b$ then $b=t*t''$
- $d$ divides $t$ then $t=rd$
- $t$ can be expressed as the linear combination $t=ax +by$

That is all the information that I have.

I don't know how to start. I tried to start by

$\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d}=\frac{t}{d}=\dots$ but I keep getting nowhere.

> How should I proceed?

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: Did not know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that there exist $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t.

$$\gcd(a,b) = ax + by$$

Now divide both sides by $d$ to get that:

$$\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d} = \frac ad x + \frac bd y$$

From here we conclude that $\gcd\left(\frac ad, \frac bd\right)$ divides $ \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d}$

Similarly we have that there exist $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t

$$\gcd\left(\frac ad, \frac bd\right) = \frac ad s + \frac bd t$$

Multiply both sides by $d$ to get that

$$d \cdot\gcd\left(\frac ad, \frac bd\right) = a s + b t$$

From here we get that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $d \cdot\gcd\left(\frac ad, \frac bd\right)$

From both relation we conclude that $\gcd\left(\frac ad, \frac bd\right)= \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d}$. Hence the proof.

Comment: I know that $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$ but why $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$ divides $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d}$? Are you assuming that $\frac{a}{d}x + \frac{b}{d}y$ is multiple of $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$ ?

Comment: I mean, i know that $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=\frac{a}{d}s+\frac{b}{d}t$ but that doesn't mean that for some $r$ intger, $rs=x$ and $rt=y$, or does it?

Comment: @Karl It doesn't have to be and you don't need it. As I did in the answer multiply both sides by $d$ and then note that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides the right side.

Comment: My doubt is that you say $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$ divides $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{d} = \frac{a}{d}x + \frac{b}{d}y$ and since i know that  $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d}) =  \frac{a}{d}s + \frac{b}{d}t $ then i assume that for some $r$, $rs=x$ , $rt=y$ but i doesn't have to be.

Comment: Why do you say that $\frac{a}{d}x + \frac{b}{d}y$ is multiple of $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$?

Comment: @Karl Note that the greatest common divisor is a **divisor** of both $\frac ad$ and $\frac bd$. Hence it divides both terms on the right and so it must divide the whole right side

Comment: Right, because $\gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})$ can be expressed as the minimum linear combination of $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$, but beacuase divides both $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ divides *any* linear combination such as $\frac{a}{d}x + \frac{b}{d}y$

Comment: You don't use the hipothesis though, is not necessay? Maybe to know that $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ are intgers ?

Comment: What initial assumption?

Comment: That d is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Karl It's used multiple times. One to conclude that $\frac ad $ and $\frac bd$ are integers and the other to write $d=ax+by$.

Comment: To conclude that $\frac{a}{d}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ are intgers i agree, but it's never written $d$ as $d=ax +by$. In any case $d$ divides $ax +by$, for any $x,y$ because $d \neq \gcd(a,b)$ right?

Comment: @Karl You have that any number that is divisible by $d=\gcd(a,b)$ can be written in the form $ax+by$. In fact the opposite direction is also true, which is what we used.

Answer (score 0):

You may also show it by direct calculation using prime factor decomposition.

Let $p_1, \ldots , p_n$ be the primes occuring in the decompositions of $a$ and $b$. Then

- $a = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}$, $b = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i} $ and $g = \gcd{(a,b)} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{g_i} $ with $g_i = \min{(a_i,b_i)}$
- $d = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{d_i} $ with $d_i \leq g_i$ and $\frac{a}{d} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i-d_i}$, $\frac{b}{d} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i-d_i}$
- $G = \gcd{(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{G_i} $ with $G_i = \min{(a_i-d_i,b_i-d_i)} = \min{(a_i,b_i)}-d_i = g_i-d_i$

It follows immediately
$$\frac{\gcd{(a,b)}}{d} =\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{g_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{d_i}} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{g_i-d_i} = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{G_i} = \gcd{(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})}$$